# different between pyscripter and python shell?

Tags: python, numpy, pyscripter

when I wrote this program in python shell i could see the result easily:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([0,1,2,3])
a
```

and the output is array([0,1,2,3]) but when I do it in `pyscripter` and I run the program nothing happen!I should to write it in this form `print(a)`and the I saw the [0,1,2,3]
what's the problem?

Comment: If you want to print the same thing, you have to use `repr`: `print repr(a)`

Answer (score 0):

When you execute it in pyscripter, I assume you wrote

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([0,1,2,3])
a
```

in main. The function will return None (default return value of a function without a return), which is why you see nothing in the pyscripter interpreter. Try `return a` instead and you should see it.

Comment: as I said I try this code in python 2.7 and I see the result!what's different?

Comment: Thats because when you do it in an interpreter, it automatically returns a when you call it. When you do it in pyscripter, it runs a function which does not automatically return it.